# Android sending Lat Long to php and storing in mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, location, android-volley

So I am using Android `points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();` to track a users GPS location every 3 seconds, which sometimes can be up to 1,000's or more points if they are on a route long enough. What is the best method for sending this route after they finish to my php and storing it into mysql? I am currently using volley to connect to my database, but it seems to time out if I try to send too much information in a loop, IE each location individually.

Here is how I get my LatLng:

```
mLastLocation = location;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
points.add(latlng);
```

Here is my volley request:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_FOR_GPS,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("GPS save route", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("command", "saveGPSroute");
            params.put("userId", userId);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: try using firebase database... 
The app should update the firebase database the geo location cordinates which will be faster then calling a service that would store in in the mysql

Comment: You can also try to send all the points at the end when user is finished traveling

Comment: you can send all the location data as json  , it will be much more efficient i guess

Comment: @HarshPatel I tried that and volley times out if I send them individually in a loop. I don't really understand JSON Objects, but I am looking into a way of doing it that way as well, not sure if volley will time out that way.

Comment: try sending json array instead of sending single item at a time

Comment: 3 seconds is very short time to get latitude and longitude also you will face battery drain problem. And in 3 seconds mobile wont travel 500 meter or 1 kilometer. So better increase you interval to 30 seconds or 1 minute!

Comment: And still if you want to send at interval of 3 sec then better to store all lat&lon on local storage and after every 1 minute send all the data from local. And send your data in json format or in string array.

Comment: Personally, I would have logged Lat and Long into local app database (firebase or not, doesn't matter at this point IMO) and synchronize it with the server every once in a while. The actual logic for me would probably be sync the locations in bulk only when the app detects, that the user has not moved for a (long) while.

Answer (score 0):

I am storing on onLocationChanged() in shared preference with count and every time i am increasing count.

then i have created one method which collect latlong from shared preference and i am making  json array. Send data with POST method don't use GET method to send large amount of json data.

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


             editdata.putString("latitude" + data_count,
                        "" + location.getLatitude());

                editdata.putString("longitude" + data_count,
                        "" + location.getLongitude());

                editdata.putString("bearing" + data_count,
                        "" + location.getBearing());
                editdata.putInt("count", data_count);
                data_count++;
              editdata.commit();

 }

 //collect data from preference like 
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

JsonArray strJson ;

  public void parse(){ 
        arr_list .clear();

        for (int i = first; i < tripdata.getInt("count", 0); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("lat", "" + latitude);
            map.put("long", "" + longitude);
            map.put("bearing", bearing);

            arr_list.add(map);

}


         if (arr_list.size() > 0) {
            strJson = new JSONArray(arr_list).toString();
            strJson = "{\"latlng\":" + strJson + "}";
      }
   }

  //here strJson  is yout JSONArray Latlong data list
```